# Laravel insert dynamic inputs into database

Tags: database, laravel, dynamic

I'm trying to save dynamic inputs in multiple rows in my database.

This is a part of my form which are payments and dates.

```
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-md-2">
                        {{Form::text('pay[]', '', ['class' => 'form-control number', 'placeholder' => ''])}}
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-md-2">
                        {{Form::text('payDate[]', '', ['class' => 'form-control pDate', 'placeholder' => ''])}}
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-md-2"><a class="deleteRow"></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

My JS code that add inputs dynamically:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var counter = 0;

$("#addrow").on("click", function () {
    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";

    cols += '<td><input type="text" id="field_2" class="form-control" name="pay[]" /></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control pDate" name="payDate[]" /></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDel btn btn-md btn-danger "  value="Delete"></td>';

    newRow.append(cols);
    $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
    counter++;
});
```

And this is my Controller:

```
    $input = $request->all();
    for($i=0; $i<= count($input['pay']); $i++) {
        $payment = new Payment;
        $payment->file = $file;
        $prePayment = str_replace(',', '', $request->input('pay'));
        $payment->payment = $prePayment;
        $payment->paymentDate = $request->input('payDate');
        $payment->save();
    }
```

Could you please help me to fix this issue.

At the moment I get this error:

Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into `payments` (`file`, `payment`, `paymentDate`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be `$request->input('pay')` this line causing the problem as you are trying to fetch whole array here, instead you should fetch `single` object.

```
$input = $request->all();
$pays = $request->input('pay');
$paymentDates = $request->input('payDate');
for($i=0; $i< count($input['pay']); $i++) {
    $payment = new Payment;
    $payment->file = $file;
    $prePayment = $pays[$i];
    $payment->payment = str_replace(',','',$prePayment);
    $payment->paymentDate = $paymentDates[$i];
    $payment->save();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have a javascript on my pay input which add separator to my number for example I type 1000 and it becomes 1,000 and my database column is integer so I need to remove seperator comma before inserting to the database. when I use $pays = str_replace(',','',$request->input('pay')); I get this error: Undefined offset: 2

Comment: It is strange, data goes to database but still I get Undefined offset: 2. This line is red also when I get an error : $prePayment = $pays[$i];